# Access differences between cache and session in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, caching

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC5 Application, I know that the actions where `session["foo"] = bar` are ran sequentially, now to avoid this, i want to store some informations into a MemoryCache object and not in session, but my doubt is: Is the cache managed like the session? So the actions where i put  `ObjectCache.Set("foo", bar, null)` are ran sequentially like for session?
I know the scope difference between cache and session but for me and in this case it's not important.

Thank to everyone

Comment: What do you mean by `ran sequentially` ?

Comment: sorry, I forget some informations, if the same user call at the same time two actions where a session variable is set I noticed that the requests are served synchronously and I read that this happens because session is static and as.net avoid problems running the requests sequentially

Comment: no the cache is not run sequentially, but you must have disable session on the page that you make the call... (or else the page is under the session lock that you try to avoid)

Comment: @Aristos Thanks a lot! this is what I need!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you try to avoid the session lock on the page.

The cache is not lock the full page access so the answer is that the cache is not run sequentially.

There are two kind of cache, one in memory that use static dictionary to keep the data and one that save the cache on database, that use files to save the data. Both of them **locks the data only for the period of read/write**, while **the session is lock the full access on the page from start to the end of it**.

So use cache, but close the session on the page you have this issue. Also have in mind that if you use web garden then the cache on memory can have multiple different data because memory cache have its own static space on each pool.

Also the session is different for each user, the cache is the same for all users.

some more to read : [ASP.NET Server does not process pages asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284530/asp-net-server-does-not-process-pages-asynchronously)

Comment: ok thank you I don't use Web Garden so for my scenario it's a good thing to use MemoryCache, thanks a lot you clarify my doubts!

Answer (score 1):

I think the term you are looking for is thread safety - especially around concurrent access, typically writing.

Seems that according to MSDN, `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` is indeed thread safe. See also: [Is MemoryCache.Set() thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738151/is-memorycache-set-thread-safe)