# is it possible not to expire for CacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration at the specific time?

Tags: c#, caching, memorycache

Is it possible not to expire for `CacheItemPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration` at the specific time?

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.absoluteexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx) there is written:

> The period of time that **must pass before a cache entry is evicted**.

As I understand this sentence means that **no less than** the specific time... is it possible if I set 12 hours, but the record will expire (let's say) only in 12.5 hours? (I mean it's not documented, it will take not less than 12 hours, but 12.5 hours is also possible or even more, right?)

for example:
I set `UpdateCallback` and `AbsoluteExpiration = 60seconds` for my `CacheItemPoice`, in practice it's called once in 80 seconds. (I logged it)

Inside `UpdateCallback` I set new values for `CacheEntryUpdateArguments`, I mean new `UpdatedCacheItem` (the same key and new data) and `UpdatedCacheItemPolicy` (the same period of time and the same `UpdateCallback`)

Comment: What are your concerns? Unless there is a polling or synchronization primitives behind I'd expect the item will expire (and will have to be re-read) on access to it. So if you access it 20 sec later it will still exists that long in the cache.

Comment: I created a self-cache updater, I need that it automatically update itself every 12 hours, and I want to know: is it possible that cache will not be expired in 12 hours? (for example, sometimes 12, sometimes 12.2, sometimes, 12.7, and 12 again.. and so on...)

Comment: So it's a [polling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12630168/1997232), thus it's not accurate, this 20 sec is ok (see accepted answer).