# .Net Core MemoryCache PostEvictionCallback not working properly

Tags: .net, caching, asp.net-core, memorycache

I have set cache items with sliding expiration in a Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache. 
I want to trigger a callback everytime a cache item expires, but callback isn't triggered until I query the cache for the expired cache item.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace Memcache
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static MemoryCache _cache;
        private static int _cacheExpSecs;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
            _cacheExpSecs = 2;

            var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
            .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_cacheExpSecs))
            .RegisterPostEvictionCallback(callback: EvictionCallback);

            _cache.Set(1, "One", cacheEntryOptions);
            _cache.Set(2, "Two", cacheEntryOptions);

            var autoEvent = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);

            System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(checkCache, autoEvent, 1000, 6000);

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void checkCache(Object o)
        {
            if(_cache.Get(1)!=null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"checkCache: Cache with key {0} will be removed manually and will trigger the callback.", 1));
                _cache.Remove(1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("checkCache: Cache with key {0} is expired.", 1));
            }


            if(_cache.Get(2) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("checkCache: Cache with key {0} will expire in {1} seconds, but won't trigger the callback until we check it's value again.", 2, _cacheExpSecs));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("checkCache: Cache with key {0} is expired.", 2));
            }

        }

        private static void EvictionCallback(object key, object value, EvictionReason reason, object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("/*****************************************************/");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("/*  EvictionCallback: Cache with key {0} has expired.  */", key));
            Console.WriteLine("/*****************************************************/");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is happening because the item is not evicted till you query for the item and it checks the expiration

(From the Source of [`MemoryCacheStore.Get(MemoryCacheKey key)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCacheStore.cs,ae04d12e168ec1ab))

```
    internal MemoryCacheEntry Get(MemoryCacheKey key) {
        MemoryCacheEntry entry = _entries[key] as MemoryCacheEntry;
        // has it expired?
        if (entry != null && entry.UtcAbsExp <= DateTime.UtcNow) {
            Remove(key, entry, CacheEntryRemovedReason.Expired);
            entry = null;
        }
        // update outside of lock
        UpdateExpAndUsage(entry);
        return entry;
    }
```

or when [`Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) is called internally due to memory pressure

(From the Source of [`TrimInternal(int percent)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCacheStore.cs,83671340f41de22b))

```
/*SNIP*/
        trimmedOrExpired = _expires.FlushExpiredItems(true);
        if (trimmedOrExpired < toTrim) {
            trimmed = _usage.FlushUnderUsedItems(toTrim - trimmedOrExpired);
            trimmedOrExpired += trimmed;
        }
/*SNIP*/
```

If your system is not currently low enough on memory to trigger a trim then the only time items will be evicted is when they are attempted to be retrieved.

Comment: Thanks. There is ExpirationScanFrequency option in MemoryCacheOptions, but neither works.

Comment: You might want to unaccept my answer for now. I totally overlooked this was .NET Core. Checking the Core source now that my statements are still correct

Comment: Ok, the logic is still the same. `ExpirationScanFrequency` is the frequency it does a full scan after any kind of Get or Remove is peformed. If the time has been longer than the `ExpirationScanFrequency` it does a full scan of items instead of just the one it was working with, It still does not run a timer to perform the scans, they are all still done on demand when a action is perfomed.

Comment: If you wanted to you could call `_cache.Compact(0)` on your own timer and that would flush out the expired entries on a regular basis.

Comment: Thank you, I'll use Compact(0). On the other hand, in .NET framework, System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache triggers the callback when sliding expiration cache item is expired.

Comment: Thanks for this. Impossible to overstate how much time incomplete documentation wastes!

Answer (score 52):

To add onto the accept answer and comments, you can force the cache to expire and evict automatically by using a expiring cancellation token.

```
int expirationMinutes = 60;
var expirationTime = DateTime.Now.Add(expirationMinutes);
var expirationToken = new CancellationChangeToken(
    new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(expirationMinutes + .01)).Token);

var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
         // Pin to cache.
         .SetPriority(CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove)
         // Set the actual expiration time
         .SetAbsoluteExpiration(expirationTime)
         // Force eviction to run
         .AddExpirationToken(expirationToken)
         // Add eviction callback
         .RegisterPostEvictionCallback(callback: CacheItemRemoved, state: this);
```

`

The lack of built in timer behavior, which the old one used to have, is supposed to be by design and this is what was recommended in its place. See: https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/248

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for and can confirm that cache does not need to be hit for this to trigger.

Comment: Worked great, minor fyi had to change `DateTime.Now.Add(...)` to `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(...)` on aspnetcore 5+.